# Сумма квадратов тригонометрических функций

Tags: математика

Дано: `tan(t) + ctan(t) = 2.4`
Как найти `tan^2(t) + ctan^2(t)`, используя формулы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Элементарно, Ватсон!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь раскройте скобки (возведите их содержимое в квадрат) и получите то, что вы ищете. 
Если для вас это сложно - вы точно гуманитарий, и ошиблись в выборе профессии :)

P.S. Это не доведение ответа до конечного результата - единственное, что останавливает меня от голосования за закрытие вопроса как учебного...

Comment: Единственное, что меня останавливает от голосования за ваше решение, это ваш снисходительный тон.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение. Затупил немного. Но вот по поводу "гуманитариев" чушь. Навык человека зависит от времени, потраченного на изучение какой-то дисциплины, и его заинтересованности. Да и все. Нечего людей делить на умных и тупых.

Comment: А вы считаете, что деление на гуманитариев и технарей - это деление на умных и тупых?..

Comment: @extrn Откровенно говоря, это же задание максимум для 9 класса школы. Почему так уверен? Только что сын-девятиклассник думал над задачей меньше минуты. Выдал мое решение. *КАК* я должен относиться к тому, кто, не дав себе труда подумать хотя бы 10-15 минут, начинает писать на ruSO?

Comment: Я не оправдываю ОПа, я критикую вас :)

Answer (score 0):

Начните с определений tan и  ctan, приведите дроби к общему знаменателю (в обоих выражениях)  , воспользуйтесь основным тригонометрическим тождеством.  Дальше,  думаю,  сами поймете.

Comment: Вариант уважаемого Harry проще.